# Когда ставится запятая после "смотри"?

Tags: пунктуация

Например, стоят два друга на балконе, допустим, Коля и Петя. Петя  увидел  вдалеке их общего друга Васю, и, указывая рукой на него (Васю), говорит Коле: 
"Смотри ( ) Вася!".
Что поставить в скобках ? Если поставить запятую, то получается как бы обращение к Васе, но он ведь вдалеке?

А если: "Смотри ( ) Вася идет".

Comment: Просто Вася должен выражаться точнее, чтобы Вы потом не ломали голову над пустяками.

Answer (score 4):

Смотри - ВАся!  Смотри, ВАся идет!

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Глагол смотри по своей функции близок к модальным словам (вводное слово или междометие), так как обозначает призыв к вниманию.

2) Соответственно, обособить вводное слово можно с помощью запятой или тире.

3) Обратим внимание на то, что при постановке запятой ударением  "смотри" не выделяется.

4) В то же время во всех приведенных вариантах, в том числе при наличии двоеточия, ударение подразумевается.

Answer (score 3):

***1. Смотри, Вася идёт! - 2. Смотри: Вася идёт! - 3. Смотри: Вася!*** - ***4. Смотри - Вася!***

1. Перечислительная интонация, ставим запятую.

2,3. Смотри (и увидишь), бессоюзное сложное предложение, ставим двоеточие.

4. Тире, так как с запятой это выглядело бы как обращение.

Answer (score 2):

Если поставите двоеточие, то будет уже не спутать это с обращением и не понадобится добавлять "идёт": в устной форме при правильной интонации тоже нет путаницы. Если Вася далеко и нужно не просто обратить на него внимание, а присмотреться, можно тире поставить (как и в случае, если появление Васи неожиданно или очень важно). Эти два варианта могут различаться интонацией: соответственно, низкий спокойный и высокий напряжённый тон в конце слова "смотри" - перед паузой. Если же Васе грозили бы (Смотри, Вася!), то тон слога "-ри" переходил бы из низкого в высокий (паузы перед вторым словом нет). Нет правил, напрямую связывающих пунктуацию с интонацией, но в данном конкретном случае выбор нужного знака позволяет исключить ложный смысл.

Answer (score 1):

Обращение к Коле (смотри) надо фиксировать? Надо вроде. Поэтому: запятая (двоеточие не даёт нужной паузы, в том числе визуальной). Но она одна будет означать, что это обращение к Васе. А поэтому, либо **Смотри,— Вася!**, либо **Смотри! Вася!**

Comment: Вася только что улетел на самолете, друзья его провожали. И вдруг он идет им навстречу. Смотри! Вася!

Comment: Им навстречу? Автор допустил, что они стояли на балконе. Он в курсе, что дело происходит в аэропорте?

Comment: Сначала они, действительно, стояли на балконе, потом Вася поднялся к ним на балкон, они отметили его отъезд, а потом проводили до самолета. И когда они снова увидели Васю, то были просто потрясены.

Comment: Всё дело в том, что форма "Смотри! Вася!" используется только в том случае, когда нужно передать очень сильные чувства (удивление, изумление). Если такая задача не стоит, то достаточно запятой.

Comment: Повторюсь: запятая после указания "Смотри" будет означать обращение к Васе, что невозможно да и не нужно.

Answer (score -1):

Тут чаще всего ставится именно тире, но это просто самый распространённый вариант.

Comment: Чаще всего? Кто считал, или так, на глазок?